# Need to make a high low game but cant figure out how to fix error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, game-physics

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class ASDFhighlow
{
public static void main(String[] args) 

{

  int money = 100;
        int roll1;
        int roll2;
        int userBet;
        int lostwin;
        char c;
        int determineWinnings;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();
        do

        {

            if (money < 1)
                break;
            System.out.println(" You have " + money + "  dollars. ");
            userBet = getBet(in, money);
            if (userBet == 0)
                break;

            c = getHighLow(in);
            roll1 = 1+ r.nextInt(5);
            System.out.println(" Die 1 rolls : " + roll1);
            roll2 = 1+r.nextInt(5);
            System.out.println(" Die 2 rolls : " + roll2);
            System.out.println("Total of two dice is: " + (roll1 + roll2));
            lostwin = determineWinnings(c, userBet, roll1 + roll2);

            if (lostwin < 0)
                System.out.println("You lost!");
            else
                System.out.println("You won " + lostwin + " dollars! ");
            money = money + lostwin;
        } while (money > 0);

        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }

    private static int getBet(Scanner inScanner, int moneyPot) {
        int bet;

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter an amount to bet (0 to quit): ");
            bet = inScanner.nextInt();
        } while (bet > moneyPot && bet != 0);

        return bet;
    }

    private static char getHighLow(Scanner inScanner) {
        System.out.println("High, low or sevens (H/L/S): ");
        String str = inScanner.next();

        return str.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

This is the error message:
1 error found:
File: /Users/adriendaleyfrenette/Desktop/EXAM FOLDER/ASDFhighlow.java  [line: 28]
Error: The method determineWinnings(char, int, int) is undefined for the type ASDFhighlow

i cannot figure out how to make it actually work im still new at this so any help is appriceated

Comment: You don't have a `determineWinnings` method..

Answer (score 1):

**Here's the answer**:
You have made the following method call

`lostwin = determineWinnings(c, userBet, roll1 + roll2);`

However, you have not defined the method `determineWinnings`. The only declaration of a term named `determineWinnings` is an int at the top of the main method which is never initialized. You need to create a new method that looks like this:

`private int determineWinnings(char c, int userBet, int rollSum)`

**How to figure this out the next time:**
The Error message you received tells you why the program failed. In this case, it says the method you tried to call on line 28 is not defined. Learn to look carefully at the Error messages you receive and understand what they are trying to say. If you can't figure it out from there or it is confusing, do a search for the text in the error. It may not be exactly the same wording as your error but should get you pointed in the right direction on the types of things to look for to debug your program.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `determineWinnings` as an `int` variable, and you have called a method with the same name, but you did not create any definition for the method. You need to create definition for your `determineWinnings()` method, which I can see is supposed to be of return type `int`.

You need to do something like this:

```
private static int determineWinnings(char someChar, int betAmount, int rollSum){
    //write your logic here

    return someIntegerValue;
}
```